# how to import SVG image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I had tried everything like adding dependencies but  VS Code don't show that package is downloaded.
I'm unable to use  `import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';`

[image: pubspec]

[image: Main]

Comment: Need to align your ```flutter_svg``` package as ```flutter``` package.

Answer (score 1):

You can change indent of `flutter_svg` in `pubspec.yaml` 
from

```
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.0
```

to

```
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
flutter_svg: ^0.19.0
```

Comment: I have it aligned like that, but I am still not able to use the import

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you run flutter pub get in the terminal, then flutter clean then restart your vs code it should work